# Como passar mais de um filho para componente pai no React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native

No meu App desenvolvido com React Native usando TypeScript, tenho um componente de função que gostaria que recebesse 2 filhos, mas gostaria de escolher onde eles vão aparecer no componente pai. Por exemplo:

ComponentePai.tsx

```
interface ComponentePaiProps extends ViewProps {
   title: string;
   children: React.ReactNode;
}

export function ComponentePai(props: ComponentePaiProps) {
  return (
    <View>
        {props.children}
        <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    </View>
);
}
```

Chamando o ComponentePai.tsx

```
<Titulo title='Estatísticas'>
   <Ionicons name="stats" size={24} color='white' />
   <Ionicons name="close" size={24} color='white' />
</Titulo>
```

No exemplo acima, ele renderiza os dois filhos um após o outro, mas como poderia receber os dois filhos, mas colocá-los um antes e um dois da tag **Text**?

Answer (score -1):

props.children retornará um array, então basta referenciar pelo index o filho.

```
<View>
    {props.children[0]}
    <Text>{props.title}</Text>
    {props.children[1]}
</View>
```